# How to retrive Image from client on jaxrs webservice

Tags: android, web-services, cordova, jax-rs

I m using phonegap to bulid an application.I m using cordova 1.9.0.js .In the application I need to send images to the server. I m using the code avialable here  for the client side:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

The code shows correct number of byte sent in client logcat indicating that the file transfer was successful.

How will I recevie the image at server side. I am using restfulwebservice based of jaxrs on serverside.

Please help regarding the topic as i cannot find anything.
Thanks